# programmatically reading the Manifest file?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the package name of the app then how to read the Manifest file Programmatically for getting launcher activity as well as services and receivers .

Comment: u can try xml-parsing may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
getApplication().getApplicationInfo().*(*-name,packageName,icon etc)
```

Comment: i have the third party application package name then how to get the information from the Manifest file @Haresh